# Integrating facebook tagging on website page

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-apps, tagging

Is it possible to integrate facebook tagging functionality to website page?

Example:
Making possible that my webite article visitor has functionality to tag one of his facebook friend on that article.

I know about integrating Share functionality, but because of specific reasons it is not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible anymore and has been deprecated after the Marketing update a few years ago now.

It has been replaced by the dynamic sharing buttons that you make a reference to in your post.

The other option is to actually accept facebook comments in your posts so facebook users can comment and tag their friends in the comment section directing them to your post.

Comment: Is there a way to make tagging effect with dynamic share button? Ex. make "tag your friend" button on website page which will than share post on friends wall and make him "tagged" on post?